# Get the email AD property to match with a list of given ad usernames

Tags: powershell, active-directory, powershell-4.0

I have been given a list of ad usernames in a text file and need a script to use the usernames and match them up with the ad profiles, grab the email from the users ad profile then export it with a CSV 2 columns username and emailaddress. So far the script exports the email but I'd like the adusername to be exported in the next column.

```
Get-Content C:\Users\xxx\Downloads\Users.txt |
    forEach { Get-ADUser $_ -Properties EmailAddress } |
    select -ExpandProperty EmailAddress |
    Out-File C:\Output\userslists.csv
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to export some data to a CSV file you should use the proper cmdlet especially desinged for that. And if you want to output the Name or sAMAccountName or whatever you just have to tell that with the Select-Object cmdlet:

```
Get-Content C:\Users\xxx\Downloads\Users.txt | 
    Get-ADUser -properties EmailAddress | 
        Select-Object -Property Name,sAMAccountName,EmailAddress | 
            Export-Csv -Path 'C:\Output\userslists.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Note that `Get-ADUser` can read from the pipeline, so `ForEach-Object` isn't required here. `Get-Content ... | Get-ADUser -Properties ... | Select-Object ...`

Comment: Thank you for the tip ... changed my suggestion accordingly.